# javascript menu works in all browsers except IE 9 (blank)

Tags: javascript

We have a js menu that works in all browsers I have tested with the exception of IE 9. The weird part is that it does work in IE9 in a different area of our website. IE9 keeps referring to problems in the `nav.js` file. Yet it is identical to the that is being used in the other area of the website. Needless to say I am stumped.

See:
http://rocksolidnet.com  and http://helpdesk.rocksolidnet.com in IE9.

Comment: IE9 found a syntax error with `awmlib1.js` on line 10, but the file was obfuscated. Can you post a more readable version of that file somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Your Javascript is minified and thus too cryptic for me to post code that would solve the problem, but I ran the IE9 debugger and it is returning these two errors:

```
SCRIPT1002: Syntax error
awmlib1.js, line 10 character 3622

SCRIPT5009: 'awmCreateCSS' is undefined
nav.js, line 39 character 1
```

I'm pretty sure the second one is what is causing your problem.

Comment: That is the confounding part. The javascript file nav.js is the same as being used on the second part of the site(helpdesk.rocksolidnet.com). I copied the nav.js file from that dir to the main dir just to be sure. On helpdesk, the debugger doesn't pick up anything.

Answer (score 0):

**Errors:**

```
SCRIPT1002: Syntax error 
awmlib1.js, line 10 character 3622
SCRIPT5009: 'awmCreateCSS' is undefined 
nav.js, line 39 character 1
```

different scripts on pages in your head sections..

Answer (score 0):

I have gone over each file related to the menu script in both directories. They are all identical. So how it works on one directory and not the other is mind boggling. I even changed the path to the menu scripts on index.html to point to the working scripts folder and it still responds with the same errors.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but it was in a client site that we didnt build, so I am not sure if I will be much help.  I am not sure exactly how i fixed it, but In the page where it wasnt working, i had DOCTYPE at the top, and I removed that.  Also I had comments around the includes in pages where it WAS working that looked like this

```
<body   id="phpbb" class="section-{SCRIPT_NAME} {S_CONTENT_DIRECTION}">
<!-- DO NOT MOVE! The following AllWebMenus linking code section must always be placed right AFTER the BODY tag-->
<!-- ******** BEGIN ALLWEBMENUS CODE FOR menusecond-2009 ******** -->
```

(menu script here)

Basically I just made sure every single character looked the same with those comments, and somehow along with deleting the DOCTYPe it magically worked.